# AJAX PHP- Loads the previous inserted record instead of first

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, comments

I have a raw commenting system where one can post comments. When the post button is clicked, an AJAX request is sent to the php file (process.php). In process.php, there's a while loop which retrieves all the comments and sends back to the index.php file as data.

Problem is **When I post two comments, the comment which I posted before the current one is shown in the div specified!**

index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['text'])){
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` VALUES('', '$text')");
    }
}

?>

<form action="" class="comment_post" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" value="POST">
</form>
<hr>

<div id="comments">

</div>

<script>
    $('form.comment_post').on('submit', function(){
    var that    = $(this),
        url     = that.attr('action'),
        type    = that.attr('method'),
        data    = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value= that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });     
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data
    });
    return false;
});
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : 'process.php',
        data    : {action: 'retrieve'},
        success : function(data){
            $('#comments').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){

    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'retrieve'){
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test`");

        if(mysql_num_rows($data) != 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
                $text = $row['text'];

                echo '<div class="each_comment">'.$text.'</div><br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No data to retrieve';
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: if you have primary key or date time column in test table,so add sorting like $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` order by <primary key or datetime column> desc");

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the root of your problem is this line: `that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){`. You should give your inputs an id, and grab it from there...

Comment: @kashan I tried that just now, it doesn't work.

Comment: so may be the issue is you are reading data before inserting,send request to process.php after insert.

Comment: @kashan Maybe so. I've used setInterval, and it worked fine. Only thing, I found clearing the interval complicated. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @kashan What you said above, was correct! I made a new button to load posts, and it loads all the posts properly. Even the ones which I post at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

first extend your database by a column "dateCreated"

then use this insert code:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test`,`dateCreated` VALUES('', '$text','NOW()')");
```

in your process.php use the code like this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY `dateCreated` DESC ");
```